# Problema con tiempo de ejecución en PHP

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy generando una consulta `SQL` en `Oracle` desde `PHP`, al realizar dicha consulta me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www\Pruebas\index.php on line 58

Codigo en `PHP` con consulta `SQL`:

```
// Sentencia SQL, me devuelve todos los numeros de cuenta que solicito (64.721) y luego los almaceno en el arreglo $numCuentas
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
            G300.G300CTA    AS NUMERO_CUENTA--,
            -- G300.G300NCTL   AS NOMBRE_CLIENTE
            FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300
            INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CCLF002 C002 ON G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
            INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GTGF006 G006 ON G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC AND (G006.G005TDOC = 1 OR G006.G005TDOC = 2 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 6 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 8)
            INNER JOIN BI_SRC.VCVF002 V002 ON G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID AND TRUNC(V002.V002FAPE) <= TO_DATE(:fecha,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND (TRUNC(V002.V002FCIE) >= TO_DATE(:fecha,'YYYY-MM-DD')-1 OR (V002.V002FCIE IS NULL))
            WHERE
            G300.G300TCTA  = 'V'
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000 WHERE G300.G300CTA =  M000.G300CTA)";
        // Preparacion de la consulta SQL
        $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stid->bindParam(':fecha', $fechaConsulta, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
        $stid->execute();
        // $arr = $stid->errorInfo();
        $resultado = $stid->fetchAll();
        // Almacenar resultados en un array (Todos los numeros de cuenta obtenidos)
        foreach ($resultado as $row) {
            $numCuentas[] = $row['NUMERO_CUENTA'];
        }

        //El resultado de $numCuentas son 64721 
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($numCuentas); ++$i) {
            //Consulta SQL que me devuelve los saldos con la ultima fecha encontrada, 
           //luego los almaceno en la posicion 0 del arreglo $saldo
           // y finalizo la ejecución del foreach luego de almacenar
            $sql = "SELECT 

                MAX(G305.G305FDIA) AS FECHA,
                G305.G305S01 AS SALDO

            FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300
            INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 ON G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
            WHERE G300.G300CTA = :cuenta
            GROUP BY G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
            ORDER BY MAX(G305.G305FDIA) DESC";

            $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stid->bindParam(':cuenta', $numCuentas[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
            $stid->execute();
            // $errorInfo = $stid->errorInfo();
            $answer = $stid->fetchAll();

             foreach($answer as $row) {
                $fechas[0] = $row['FECHA'];
                $saldo[0] = $row['SALDO'];
                break;
            }
            //Insertar datos en un array 
            array_push($dinero, $saldo);
        }
```

Comment: El problema es que tu consulta esta consumiendo mucho tiempo, para arreglarlo debes editar tu archivo php.ini y buscar max_execution_time = 120 y aumentarle, pero primero deberias ver si tu consulta esta bien construida,, veo que haces unas consultas dentro de un ciclo for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema parece ser que tu consulta esta tardando demasiado en ser ejecutada. Lo primero que yo te recomendaría es que trates de optimizar tu consulta y reducir el tiempo en que esta se ejecuta, en caso de no ser posible debes de aumentar el tiempo máximo de ejecución en PHP.

Esto lo puedes hacer modificando el archivo `php.ini` buscando la línea:

```
max_execution_time = 120
```

Y sustituirla por el nùmero de segundos que consideres adecuados.

Otra forma es modificando el archivo `.htaccess` y agregando la siguiente línea, igual, agregando el número de segundos que consideres adecuados:

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

Pero como te comente al inicio, te recomiendo, antes de modificar el tiempo de ejecución, que trates de mejorar tu consulta.

Saludos!